# Trigger failing to deploy after FileTransform@2 task in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm doing an initial build of three files all related to Azure Data Factory:

- Ingestion pipeline
- Ingestion mapping data flow
- Trigger

The build copies the files to a target folder and then publishes an artifact.

Up to this point everything works fine.

Next step is a release in which I want to first do substitution on the data flow and trigger files using the FileTransform@2 task.
The image below shows that the transforms on both files happened successfully even though the data flow transform had one issue (which doesn't prevent the pipeline from running and is not the root cause of the issue)

[image: View of failed release]

Looking at the final step, Deployment Completion,  the error reported is as follows:

[image: Failed pipeline log error message]

From the error message you'll see that it happens when attempting to deploy the Trigger and the error itself is correct when it talks about permissions to Write on preprod but not on dev.

That's the problem: In the previous Transform Trigger step I replace the scope property value with the correct preprod value instead of the dev value.

[image: Release pipeline variables]

This is how the FileTransform@2 task is configured:

[image: FileTransform configuration]

And here is the log file produced during the run showing that the substitution of the scope property is being done:

[image: Transform File trigger log]

Searching online, the only thought that I've come up with is that the final stage of the deployment is re-downloading the artifact which means its not looking at the transformed files. But, I don't know how to prove this or if I'm even on the right track.

How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

> the only thought that I've come up with is that the final stage of the deployment is re-downloading the artifact which means its not looking at the transformed files. But, I don't know how to prove this or if I'm even on the right track.

Yes, in release pipeline it will download the **build artifact** by default. You can disable the operation by option:
[image]

Different stages will run on different agent machines. If you'd like to use the files which generated(transformed) in previous stage, you need to use [artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to transfer the data to next stage/job.

[image]

However, in `Classic` release pipeline, [publish artifact is NOT supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-artifacts).
[image]

To use transformed file, you can check below options:

1. Put the tasks together in **one job** for stages `Transform trigger`, `Transform Data flow` and `Deployment Complete`. In one job, it can use the transformed data.
2. Use yaml to define your release pipeline, as `publish artifact` is supported. You can check the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example) for your reference.

Comment: we had the tasks together in one stage and would have preferred to keep it that way, however, the FileTransform@2 task has an issue whereby it doesn't allow enough differentiation when it comes to variable declaration and usage. E.g. a simple field like "properties.description" is used in the trigger and data flow, but using it in one job means the wrong description is being applied to the wrong file - assuming it's the last/first one that it finds in variables.

Comment: @Jacques, you are using "variable Substitution" feature on the transform task, you can re-define the variable value via [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#logging-command-format), if you add a new filestransform task, it will use the new variable value. So you can put two filestransform in one job. I confirm it's working on my side. Please elaborate a bit if there's any pain on the task.

Comment: @Jacques, may i know if there's any update? As transfer data between different stages you should use artifact, hence you need to change the pipeline definition. Another possible way is to use self-hosted agent as it can keep the data for different stages if you don't want to update the definition.